# Filter table - every table row contains a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, filtering

I have a datatable and every row should include a select item with several options, those are just examples.
On top of the table is the default search bar and I want to filter my rows by the text of the selected items.
Currently when I search for "plan" every row is shown no matter what option is selected.
When I type anything despite of "plan", "do", "check", "act" all rows are gone like it should, I guess it doesn't only search for the selected value.

I have my example code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data Table with Filters</title>
    <script src="javaScript/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="javaScript/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="javaScript/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javaScript/jquery-core-validate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="myTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Chris</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="0">Plan</option>
                        <option value="1">Do</option>
                        <option value="2">Check</option>
                        <option value="3">Act</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Anna</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="0">Plan</option>
                        <option value="1">Do</option>
                        <option value="2">Check</option>
                        <option value="3">Act</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    

<script>
    let table = new DataTable('#myTable');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#myDataTable thead tr')
            .clone(true)
            .addClass('filters')
            .appendTo('#myDataTable thead');
        var table = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();
                // For each column
                api
                    .columns()
                    .eq(0)
                    .each(function (colIdx) {
                        // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                        var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                            $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                        );
                        var title = $(cell).text();
                        $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
                        // On every keypress in this input
                        $(
                            'input',
                            $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                        )
                            .off('keyup change')
                            .on('change', function (e) {
                                // Get the search value
                                $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                                var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();
                                var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                                // Search the column for that value
                                api
                                    .column(colIdx)
                                    .search(
                                        this.value != ''
                                            ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                            : '',
                                        this.value != '',
                                        this.value == ''
                                    )
                                    .draw();
                            })
                            .on('keyup', function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                $(this).trigger('change');
                                $(this)
                                    .focus()[0]
                                    .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                            });
                    });
            },
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data Table with Filters</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <table id="myTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Chris</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="filter-select">
                        <option value="0">Plan</option>
                        <option value="1">Do</option>
                        <option value="2">Check</option>
                        <option value="3">Act</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Anna</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="filter-select">
                        <option value="0">Plan</option>
                        <option value="1">Do</option>
                        <option value="2">Check</option>
                        <option value="3">Act</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true
        });

        // Add a change event listener to the select elements with class 'filter-select'
        $('.filter-select').on('change', function () {
            // Get the selected value
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();

            // Filter the table based on the selected value in the second column (index 1)
            table.column(1).search(selectedValue).draw();
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this corrected code:

1. I removed the unnecessary scripts and simplified the inclusion of the required libraries.
2. I added the class `filter-select` to the `select` elements.
3. I removed the custom search code and utilized DataTables' built-in functionality to handle the filtering based on the selected value in the dropdown.

Comment: thanks for your anwser, but it doesn't work like it should
the search via text field still ignores the text of the selected value and shows every row no matter what value is selected
when i change the dropdown selected value the filter gets activated even though the search bar is empty.
In my case i don't need to react on changing the values. i only want to filter when the text changes in the search bar